# Why should hydrolysis break down fat into fatty acid and glycerol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrolysis

Fats and lipids are composed of carbon, hydrogen and oxygen. Both esters form different structures at different room temperatures.

Now fats and lipids are generally insoluble in polar solvents(water) and soluble in organic solvents(hexane, ether).

If this happens to be true, why should the actions of hydrolysis(chemical breakdown of a substance with the use of water) breakdown fat into fatty acid and glycerol?

Just like the enzyme lipase, uses hydrolysis to breakdown fats. Why should a polar solvent dissolve fat?

Comment: "Insoluble" doesn't mean "has zero solubility", it means "it's solubility is low or very low".

Comment: I suggest a subtle rethink here. Fats are not hydrolysed to fatty acids (long chain carboxylic acids) and glycerol ; triglycerides are. Fats tend to be solids; heavier homologues of the corresponding hydrocarbon oils.

Answer (score 0):

Lipase enzyme breaks down fats into fatty acids and glycerol, and water is essential for enzyme action/activation.